# On click re-position root node and adjust window

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've constructed a [tree graph](https://jsfiddle.net/kabamaru/xgdxvad1/).

In order to calculate the div height in my webpage I count the end-nodes (leaves) in my json object and multiply the result with 25.
Currently I have 150 leaves so div height is 3750px which is just fine.

When I hide the children I would like to re-position the root node in the center of a smaller wrapper. So I need to:

1. Calculate minimum tree height (eg. 3 end-nodes visible, `min:3*50`),
2. adjust wrapper height (div)
3. vertically align the root node in the center of wrapper
4. go back to original height when user click a parent node to show the children

   `// Toggle children on click.
   function click(d) {
     if (d.children) {
       d._children = d.children;
       d.children = null;
       // Hide children and count visible end-nodes
     } else {
       // Show children, count visible nodes recalculate height
       d.children = d._children;
       d._children = null;
     }
     update(d);
   }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this code, which you can put  inside your `function(update)`. It's not the best solution, but it's a start:

```
// compute the new height
var levelWidth = [1];
var childCount = function(level, n) {
  if(n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
    if(levelWidth.length <= level + 1) levelWidth.push(0);      
    levelWidth[level+1] += n.children.length;
    n.children.forEach(function(d) {
      childCount(level + 1, d);
    });
  }
};

childCount(0, root);  
newHeight = d3.max(levelWidth) * 50;//number of pixels per line
```

It gives you, each time you update the tree, an array of end nodes (leaves), takes the maximum in that array and multiply by a value (here I used 50, for 50 pixels per leaf). You can use this value to change the height of your div.

Check the updated fiddle and look at the console each time you click: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/b8hmwsm5/1/

Again, not the best solution, but I think that it will be ease to make some improvements here.